# How can I create a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, collections

http://diveintopython3.ep.io/native-datatypes.html

I've found that link but it seems to rely on the fact that I first have to hard create the list. How can I create a list in Python if it's empty at first. I'm coming from a C# background so this is kind of weird so far.

For example the .append() method is what I'm looking for, but it relies on the fact that the list **first exists**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Google result #7(python empty list): http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an empty list like this

```
L=list()
```

or

```
L=[]
```

Comment: Note that the second way is more idiomatic and "Pythonic".

Comment: @music freak, I think I would agree that it is more idiomatic, but it does give up some of Python's beautiful dynamicness.

Comment: @gnibbler: How so? Both examples are functionally equal, so I don't see the difference besides readability.

Comment: @musicfreak, `list` does a name lookup, so I can change the behaviour by having something in my locals() or globals() called `list`. Not saying it's a good idea here, but that type of thing can be useful in some circumstances

Comment: @musicfreak, for example if I wanted to test a module using `blist` instead of `list` see: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/

Comment: Ah, fair enough; good point! But for 99% of circumstances I'd still use the shorthand.

Comment: I've learned python by digging through the standard modules, in addition to 3rd party, and never once have seen the former method used. Checkout [more on lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists); look at how each list is instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by others, you can create an empty list with the list literal operator `[]`.

Its worth noting that you can initialise the list with values if you always need to start with a few values already in place:

```
a = 5
L = [42, -12, a]
```